# GetUserMedia crossbrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, video, media

I'm working on a media module for a custom social network, and I need to capture photos and videos from my webcam.

I looked `getUserMedia` from HTML5, but it does not work with IE, safari or with mobile..

So what can i use ? Any ideas ?

Comment: `getUserMedia` works on Android devices with Chrome. The problem with scriptcam is that it relies on Flash, which you will not find on iOS devices. I'd reckon that Safari  or Chrome for iOS should support `getUserMedia` soon (hopefully). This is a good site to keep an eye on. http://caniuse.com/stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find this API, and she is nice : [scriptcam](http://scriptcam.com)

Answer (score 0):

Flash or Java will probably do the job on IE and Safari.

You'll need a native application for mobile.

Comment: Yeah, do you know a library ? an api ?

Comment: For what? Flash? Java Applets? Java for Android? Objective-C for iOS? (The answer is going to be "no" whatever).